# AWS internal ALB gets no traffic from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a question regarding AWS API Gateway which forwards traffic to an internal facing ALB. This is configured with terraform:

```
resource "aws_lb" "foo-load-balancer" {
  name               = "foo-dev"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = true
  subnets            = local.private_subnet_ids
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_security_group.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "lb_security_group" {
  name   = "${local.name}-lb-security-group"
  vpc_id = local.vpc_id


  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8383
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = local.private_subnet_cidrs
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = local.private_subnet_cidrs
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = local.private_subnet_cidrs
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    # Allowing any incoming port
    to_port = 0
    # Allowing any outgoing port
    protocol = "-1"
    # Allowing any outgoing protocol
    cidr_blocks = [
    "0.0.0.0/0"]
    # Allowing traffic out to all IP addresses
  }
  tags = local.tags
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link" "alb-vpc-link" {
  name = local.name
  security_group_ids = [
  aws_security_group.lb_security_group.id]
  subnet_ids = local.private_subnet_ids
  tags       = local.tags
}
```

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "foo" {
  name          = "${local.name}-foo"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "foo" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.foo.id
  integration_type   = "HTTP_PROXY"
  integration_method = "ANY"
  connection_type    = "VPC_LINK"
  connection_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link.alb-vpc-link.id
  integration_uri    = module.foo-backend-service.aws_lb_listener.arn

  depends_on = [
  module.foo-backend-service]
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "foo" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.foo.id
  route_key = "ANY /{proxy+}"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.foo.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_deployment" "foo" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.foo.id
  depends_on = [
  aws_apigatewayv2_route.foo]
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "foo" {
  name          = "$default"
  deployment_id = aws_apigatewayv2_deployment.foo.id
  api_id        = aws_apigatewayv2_api.foo.id
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "foo" {
  domain_name = aws_acm_certificate.foo.domain_name

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.foo.arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }

  depends_on = [
  aws_acm_certificate_validation.foo]
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api_mapping" "foo" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.foo.id
  domain_name = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.foo.id
  stage       = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.foo.id
}
```

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "foo-service-task" {
  family                = "${var.application_name}-${var.name}-service-task"
  container_definitions = jsonencode(
  [
    {
      name: "${var.application_name}-${var.name}-service-task",
      image: var.image,
      essential: true,
      portMappings: [
        {
          containerPort: 8282,
          hostPort: var.port
        }
      ],
      memory: var.memory,
      cpu: var.cpu,
      environment: var.environment,
      logConfiguration: {
        logDriver: "awslogs",
        options: {
          awslogs-group: var.cloudwatch_group,
          awslogs-region: var.aws_region,
          awslogs-stream-prefix: var.name
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    service = var.name
  })
  depends_on = [var.depends_on_relation]
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo-service" {
  name            = "${var.application_name}-${var.name}"
  cluster         = data.aws_ecs_cluster.ecs.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.foo-service-task.arn
  desired_count   = var.desired_count

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
    container_name   = aws_ecs_task_definition.foo-service-task.family
    container_port   = 8282
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets = var.subnet_ids
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.securitygroup.id]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_lb_listener.listener]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "securitygroup" {
  name = "${var.application_name}-${var.name}"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = local.subnet_cidrs
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    # Allowing any incoming port
    to_port = 0
    # Allowing any outgoing port
    protocol = "-1"
    # Allowing any outgoing protocol
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"]
    # Allowing traffic out to all IP addresses
  }

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    service = var.name
  })
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target-group" {
  name = "${local.stage}-${var.name}"
  port = var.port
  protocol = var.protocol
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    enabled = var.health_check_enabled
    matcher = var.protocol == "TCP" ? null : "200,301,302"
    path = var.health_check_protocol == "TCP" ? null : var.health_check_path
    port = var.health_check_port
    protocol = var.health_check_protocol
    interval = var.health_check_interval
    timeout = var.protocol == "TCP" ? null : var.health_check_timeout
    healthy_threshold = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
  }
  slow_start = var.protocol == "TCP" ? null : var.health_check_slow_start

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    service = var.name
  })

  depends_on = [
    data.aws_lb.loadbalancer]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = data.aws_lb.loadbalancer.arn
  port = var.port
  protocol = var.protocol
  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target-group.arn
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_lb_target_group.target-group]
}
```

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.foo.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.hosted_zone.zone_id

  alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.foo.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.foo.domain_name_configuration[0].hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "foo" {
  domain_name       = local.application_domain
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "foo_acm" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.foo.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.hosted_zone.zone_id
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "foo" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.foo.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.foo_acm : record.fqdn]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "application_load_balancer" {
  name    = "alb.${local.application_domain}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.hosted_zone.zone_id
  ttl     = "60"
  records = [aws_lb.foo-load-balancer.dns_name]
}
```

The Service/Task, which I am starting is a simple Spring-Boot app ("Greeting-Controller") with an enabled health-check. The service is up and running and healthy.

The problem is the ALB doesn't recognize any traffic (I can't see any requests at the ALB in the AWS console) and when I try to access to the registered Route53 DNS I get the "Service unavailable" JSON.

Any ideas what to change?

Comment: The ALB does not work at all, or only from the API? What if you spin up an instance in your vpc and `curl` your internal load balancer?

Comment: Looks like the ALB doesn't work. `curl` or `ping` doesn't work. But another working ALB (configured from someone else) isn't reachable too from the started ec2 instance

Comment: Does your ecs service work? Can you curl it directly?

Comment: The instance must be in your `private_subnet_cidrs`. Make sure it is in the subnets which are included in ALB security groups.

Comment: How did it go? Any progress?